# Efficient way to insert a list data into a mySQL database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, loops

I have csv files which I would like to dump into a db. so I crated a loop of the files, and inside the loop I have created a list called data for each line

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(itemChecked.ToString());//read the file

while ((line = file.ReadLine())  != null)
{
    if (start_flag == true) // start processing the numbers, get the real data
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.AddRange(line.Replace("\"", "").Split(',').AsEnumerable());
    }
}
```

so far so good.

Now I want to insert the list data into the database. The list is quite large. I don't want to type every single one of them like so:

```
insert into table1 (tablenames) values (a, b, c on and on)
```

How can I loop the list and insert the data into the database?

Comment: Why are you doing this with C#? If you don't have to do that, there are instructions [here](http://www.billsternberger.net/mysql/import-csv-file-to-mysql/) on how to do this natively for MySql.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you executed any commands to mysql db?

Comment: Please [look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592196/mysql-bulk-insert-a-text-file), it seems exactly the response for you

Comment: If you still want to roll your own data importer, at least try to use [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I must do this in c#. It's an application and inserting the data into the db is just the small part of the app. Btw, I have done numerous projects/apps with C# and mysql. No problem at all. If I had to switch to sql server the question would be the same.

Comment: Then LinqToCSV should be helpful in encapsulating at least the read part http://linqtocsv.codeplex.com/. Seems like you need to directly read the input into something from ADO.Net that can just be flushed to your new DB, rather than a list of strings?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to use [the ADO.NET Driver for MySQL (Connector/NET)](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) to connect to the database.

Second, you will want to open a connection to the database, and then insert some data:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection();
connection.ConnectionString =
   "server=localhost;"
    + "database=DBNAME;"
    + "uid=USERNAME;"
    + "password=PASSWORD;";

connection.Open();

foreach(var datum in data) 
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText =
        "insert into table1 (tablenames)"
        + " values "
        + "(a, b, c on and on)";

    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

My example was [based off this article](http://markalexanderbain.suite101.com/how-to-add-records-to-mysql-with-c-a120775). This isn't a perfect solution, but it should get you started. You may want to [look into MySQL Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html) to batch your inserts into efficient groupings (depending on data size maybe 100-1000 at a time.)

Comment: I need to loop on the values not on the insert. I have a list which contain the values

Comment: Maybe some sample data would be useful, because I don't think I understand what you're trying for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use bulkcopy to import all the data from the csv file at once. You can find a sample right here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30705/C-CSV-Import-Export

I hope this is what you are looking for

Greetings